# Django "UPDATE `django_session`" killing performances

Tags: mysql, django

My Django client was very slow during MySQL queries. Doing a tcpdump on the MySQL server, I saw that the following SQL query

```
"UPDATE `django_session` SET `session_data` = " [data]
```

is very long. What is the simplest way to solve this problem ?
Thank you.

------------------------- EDIT 1

the size of [data] is very big and it is taking a very long time to transfer.

------------------------- EDIT 2

mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM django_session;

| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name                            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |

+----------------+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

| django_session |          0 | PRIMARY                             |            1 | session_key | A         |        9496 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |

| django_session |          1 | django_session_expire_date_a5c62663 |            1 | expire_date | A         |        9496 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |

2 rows in set (0,02 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE django_session;

| Table          | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| django_session | CREATE TABLE `django_session` (
  `session_key` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `session_data` longtext NOT NULL,
  `expire_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_key`),
  KEY `django_session_expire_date_a5c62663` (`expire_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

1 row in set (0,01 sec)

Comment: Try setting atomic requests to true https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests

Comment: Show us the A) entire query, B) SHOW INDEX FROM table_name; and C: SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name; so we have some idea the scope of your effort.

Comment: I just edited the question, the "entire query" is UPDATE with a very big session_data.

Comment: @WilsonHauck do you have a specific table in mind for (B) and (C) ? Would that be a specific django table ? I guess it has something to do with django settings  session ?

Comment: Yes, django_session for both SHOW INDEX and SHOW CREATE TABLE.
If you can not post the whole query, how can you possibly run it?  Do you have a SHORT version of the 'complete query'?  We need to see what you are doing start from beginning to ;  when the query is handed to the optimizer.

Comment: I am not posting the whole query because [data] is very big binary data.

Comment: Great.  Short complete query with just 3 examples of your binary data  elements would be fine as long as we can see the WHERE .......   ORDER BY and other details.

Comment: The UPDATE finishes with this: , `expire_date` = '2018-02-23 14:38:48' WHERE `django_session`.`session_key` = 'XXXX' and there is pretty much for 15MB of [data] in the tcpdump.